# Ambigious call to overloaded function when using lambda

Tags: c++, lambda, windows-runtime, c++-winrt

Never used lambdas before and I can't understand where I'd have to add it.

My Error is "Show: Ambigious call to overloaded function"

`Show()` can take 2 types `CustomizeToast` and `CustomizeToastAsync`. So I guess I need to specify `CustomizeToast` somewhere but I can't for the life of me see where.

This is my current code:

```
ToastContentBuilder()
    .AddText(L"Hello World!")
    .Show([](ToastNotification const& toast) -> void
    {
       toast.Tag(L"1");
    });
```

Error:

```
error C2668: 'winrt::impl::consume_Microsoft_Toolkit_Uwp_Notifications_IToastContentBuilderClass<winrt::Microsoft::Toolkit::Uwp::Notifications::IToastContentBuilderClass>::Show': ambiguous call to overloaded function
Microsoft.Toolkit.Uwp.Notifications.0.h(2159,60): message : could be 'auto winrt::impl::consume_Microsoft_Toolkit_Uwp_Notifications_IToastContentBuilderClass<winrt::Microsoft::Toolkit::Uwp::Notifications::IToastContentBuilderClass>::Show(const winrt::Microsoft::Toolkit::Uwp::Notifications::CustomizeToastAsync &) const'
Microsoft.Toolkit.Uwp.Notifications.0.h(2158,31): message : or       'auto winrt::impl::consume_Microsoft_Toolkit_Uwp_Notifications_IToastContentBuilderClass<winrt::Microsoft::Toolkit::Uwp::Notifications::IToastContentBuilderClass>::Show(const winrt::Microsoft::Toolkit::Uwp::Notifications::CustomizeToast &) const'
message : while trying to match the argument list '(winrt::MyApplication::implementation::Toast::ShowToastNotification::<lambda_786678859ea03b85c00686eebdcb39db>)'
```

Project is an UWP project using the Microsoft.Toolkit.Uwp.Notifications

Comment: Please provide full error message, in addition to [mre].

Comment: if `Show` can either take a `CustomizeToast` or a `CustomizeToastAsync` and both can be constructed from the lambda, then the compiler cannot know which one to pick. I have to guess, but the complete compiler error should tell all this in a much more concise way. Without code and complete error message we can only guess

Comment: Added Error Message, this is all I have in my ShowToastNotification function and should work fine with an empty UWP Solution and the Microsoft.Toolkit.Uwp.Notification Package

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> `Show()` can take 2 types `CustomizeToast` and `CustomizeToastAsync`.

This is clearly an oversight on the API's developpers end. Now since both classes can be constructed from a lambda the compiler doesn't know which one to use, so you have to guide it:

```
ToastContentBuilder()
    .AddText(L"Hello World!")
    .Show(CustomizeToast{[](ToastNotification const& toast) -> void
    {
       toast.Tag(L"1");
    }});
```

This is less readable and cumbersome, but constructing syntaxic suggar for it would be error-prone and a bit convoluted.

Comment: *"This is clearly an oversight on the API's developpers end."* - Or, just something one has to live with when C++' overly complex overload resolution kicks in. If you cannot help it but need to point fingers, don't ignore what a mess C++ has turned into.

Comment: @IInspectable I stand by my words.

Comment: Don't think you can really blame C++ here. It would be trivial for the API developers to add an `ShowCustomizeToast` method, not overloaded. This will not break any existing code, and be a pure extension. The overloaded `Show(CustomizeToast)` would then be a simple shorthand, and probably an `inline` wrapper.

Comment: The API developer doesn't know about C++, nor lambda expressions. Nor about crazy constructors that take function-like objects.

Comment: @IInspectable I'm lost. Is it not a C++ API? Shouldn't its devs know of a major, 10-years-old C++ feature?

Comment: No, it's not. It's a Windows Runtime type. The C++ code is [generated](https://aka.ms/cppwinrt).

Comment: @msa Adding a function to an interface is a breaking change. That's true with C++ (which doesn't have an answer to this problem) and the Windows Runtime (which, incidentally, has a solution to interface versioning). The change may look trivial, but it's not free. Code that wants to call `ShowCustomizeToast` will now also have to call `QueryInterface` (and `Release`). That's a non-trivial cost.

Comment: @IInspectable _that_ was the information I was lacking. That's bold to generate a C++ interface. I would certainly avoid it.

Comment: It's only bold if you aren't [Kenny Kerr](https://kennykerr.ca).